# How to exclude a $row['weight'] from $cat_fields

Tags: php

Hi can you please help me to exclude a row from this peace of script:

```
<?php 
    if($ad_fields!="")  { 
     foreach ($ad_fields as $key => $value)
        {
          echo " <nobr><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; ".$cat_fields[$key][0].": </strong>". 
      " ".$ad_fields[$key].$fld_dim[$key].$fld_dimd[$key].";<br /> </nobr> "; }} 
?>
```

This script echo all rows, how can I achieve that script doesn't call out for example $row['weight'], or $row['weight'] & $row['height']

Thanks

Comment: You mean, other than `if($key === 'weight' || $key === 'height') continue;`?

Comment: I wan't to exclude weight, height. I want to keep others, for example title, name,...

Answer (score 1):

Your code-sample doesn't have a variable named `$row`, so I'm assuming you're referring to `$cat_fields`, `$ad_fields`, `$fld_dim`, or `$fld_dimd` (which all appear to have the same keys).

You can check the value of the `$key` in the `foreach`-loop. If it matches a value you don't want to display, use `continue;` to skip:

```
foreach ($ad_fields as $key => $value) {
    if (($key == 'weight') || ($key == 'height')) continue;
```

Alternatively, you can define an array of keys you want to skip and check with `in_array()`:

```
$skipKeys = array('weight', 'height');
foreach ($ad_fields as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $skipKeys)) continue;
```

The second option may be better if your list of keys-to-skip grows rather long.

Comment: Will try second option. Thank you.